# Assigning object properties values to an array or variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have this object:

```
{
  nameErr: "Name is required"
  numberErr: "Number is required"
  emailErr: "Email is required"
  genderErr: "Gender is required"
  messageErr: "Message is required"
}
```

And this array:

```
var errorVars = [errorName, errorNumber, errorEmail, errorGender, errorMessage]
```

How can I assign the value of the property `nameErr` to the `errorVars` variable and do the same to the rest variables in the array, is it possible?

Something like:

```
for(i=0; i<errorVars.length; i++){
  errorVars[i] = "property value[i]"
}
```

PS: Using pure JavaScript.

Comment: You are using two objects. `errorVars` is going to be object after you do what you want to do, which leads to useless copying, why don't you use first object?.

Comment: @Oen44 I want to print the properties in html tags. If I have this propertie {name:"my name"} is possible to print "my name" in a span tag in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from comment above your problem is how to select object value, you can select it with `obj.keyName` or if it dynamic keys use `Object.keys(obj)`

```js
var obj = {
  nameErr: "Name is required",
  numberErr: "Number is required",
  emailErr: "Email is required",
  genderErr: "Gender is required",
  messageErr: "Message is required"
};
var errorVars = []
// select by key
console.log(obj.nameErr + "\n\n")

// for dynamic key
for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  objValue = obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]];
  console.log(objValue)
  // convert to array
  errorVars.push(objValue)
}
console.log(errorVars)
```

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for, thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of converting an object into an array using vanilla JS:

```
var ob = {
    nameErr: "Name is required",
    numberErr: "Number is required",
    emailErr: "Email is required",
    genderErr: "Gender is required",
    messageErr: "Message is required"
 }

var errorVars = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(ob).length; i++) {
    var x = Object.keys(ob)[i]
    errorVars.push(x + " : " + ob[x]
};

console.log(errorVars);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. There are 2 options:
1) you can make it in the same order, so

```
`var obj ={
nameErr: "Name is required"
//...
}
for(i=0; i<errorVars.length; i++){
  errorVars[i] = obj[i];
}`
```

2) you need to modify little bit your `errorVars`  structure to

```
`var errorName ={
      name:"nameErr", value:""
};
var errorVars = [errorName];
for(i in errorVars) {
   errorVars[i].value = obj[errorVars[i].name];
}`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @YCotov The first option returns undefined when I console.log, the second one require that I modify my object and I preefer to not do it because is an object form Json.